# Returning the base URL in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use the base URL in an object:

```
      {
        id: "1",
        url: {baseURL} + "/img1.jpg",
        fileName: "img1.jpg",
      }
```

Here is how I'm trying to do it:

```
const currentRoute= window.location.pathname
```

But this is returning `[object Object]/images/img1.jpg`.

Comment: Remove the brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if baseURL is a string, then `{baseURL}` would convert it to an object. And due to the openness of javascript, it would try to call the `toString()` method on the object which would result in [object Object].

You should try using string templates like `${baseURL}/img1.jpg` or just do `baseURL + "/img1.jpg"`. And if the baseURL is inside the currentRoute then do `currentRoute.baseURL + "/img1.jpg"` or destructure it before concatenation like - `const { baseURL } = currentRoute;` then do `url: baseURL + "/img1.jpg"`. Check [this link for more info on object destructuring.](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-object-destructuring-spread-operator-rest-parameter/)

Answer (score 1):

```js
      {
        id: "1",
        url: baseURL + "/img1.jpg", // => remove brackets
        fileName: "img1.jpg",
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use brackets, you need to use Template Literals.

Else you can just do what the others in this Post has said, just remove the barcketes.

```
let object = {
    id: "1",
    url: `${baseUrl}/img1.jpg`, // Example of a template literal.
    fileName: "img1.jpg",
  }
```